# SQL Server : select random rows of each type

Tags: sql-server

I have following table:

```
id | customer | type
---+----------+------
 1 | Joe      | 5
 2 | Sally    | 3
 3 | Joe      | 2
 4 | Sally    | 1
 5 | Bob      | 5
 6 | Clark    | 5
 7 | Daniel   | 1
 8 | Mike     | 3
```

and following data:

```
count | type
------+------
2     | 5
1     | 1
1     | 3
```

or just array:

```
(5, 5, 1, 3)
```

I need select 2 random unique customers of type 5, 1 customer of type 1 and 1 customer of type 3 **in one request**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is like juergen's approach but it'll work with any configuration of types.

```
select t1.id
  from 
       (
        select c.id, 
               t.count,
               row_number () over (partition by t.type order by newid()) as rn
           from customerTable c join typeTable t on c.type = t.type) as t1
where t1.rn <= t1.count;
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I need